# When trying to get propertis from object, get UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have problem with geting object props...

Here is my json file

```
formControlOptions: any[] = [
    {
        { type: "INPUT",
            value: "none,"
        }
    },
    {
        type: "SELECT_BOX",
            value: "none",
            options: ["select option 1", "select option 2", "select option 3"]

    },
    {
        type: "RADIO_BTN",
            value: "none",
            options: ["radio option 1", "radio option 2", "radio option 3"]

    }
];
```

Here is where I try to get data. I try to make `JSON.parse()` also, but always I get `UNDEFINED`

```
for (let v of this.formControlOptions) {
            if (Object.keys(v) === "INPUT") {
                console.log(v); // { INPUT: { value: "none" })
                console.log(typeof v); // object
                console.log(v.value); // undefined
                console.log(Object.keys(v).value); // undefined
                console.log(JSON.parse(v).value); // undefined
            }
```

Comment: You should really really stop using `==` for scenarios, in which you don't explicitly want loose equals.

Comment: this is only for example... in this case i get true like i expect and get all `console.logs`

Comment: Also, you are doing programming by trial and error - you already logged `v`, you want `v.INPUT.value`.

Comment: `Object.keys(v)` returns an array, that would never equal `INPUT`?

Comment: v.value is undefined because v is an object = `{INPUT: { value: "none" }}`, so you have to check v.INPUT.value, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. I advise you change the structure of your json. So probably add a key called type where you save the input type in. I could explain better if you don't understand this.

Comment: "_Here is my json file_" That is not JSON. It's an array. JSON is a string representation of a JavaScript Object. As you noticed, `typeof v` is _not_ a string. It doesn't make sense to parse JSON if it isn't a string.

Comment: @its_tayo thnx, if you can explain it better. I create JSON file only for test purpose, because I waiting for the backend to be done, until that i try some ideas with reusable components...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, this is an array and as I understand you're trying to add mock data pending when actual API is ready. Object.keys returns an array containing all keys in an object. So `Object.keys(v) === "INPUT"` is false. `v.value` is undefined because v is an object that does not have value as a key. I think what you should be doing there is `v.INPUT.value`.

I suggest you change the structure of your array. So you have:

```
const formControlOptions: {
  inputType: string;
  label: string;
  defaultValue: string | string[];
  options?: string[];
}[] = [
  {
    inputType: "text",
    label: "Input label",
    defaultValue: ""
  },
  {
    inputType: "select",
    label: "Select label",
    defaultValue: "",
    options: ["select option 1", "select option 2", "select option 3"]
  },
  {
    inputType: "radio",
    label: "Radio label",
    defaultValue: "",
    options: ["select option 1", "select option 2", "select option 3"]
  },
  {
    inputType: "checkbox",
    label: "Checkbox label",
    defaultValue: [],
    options: ["check option 1", "check option 2", "check option 3"]
  }
];
```

Then you can map over the array and use the `inputType` to set appropriate inputT types.